# Bluetooth send a text to other device

Tags: android, bluetooth

i have a simple question:

first, this is all my code:

> package com.example.mybluetoothapp;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<BluetoothDevice> devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    public UUID serverUuid = UUID.fromString("SERVEUR");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Votre appareil n'a pas de Bluetooth",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent bluetoothIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(bluetoothIntent, 1);
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter
                .getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice : pairedDevices) {
                devices.add(bluetoothDevice);
            }
        }

        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent
                            .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    devices.add(device);
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);

        Intent dicoverableIntent = new Intent(
                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        dicoverableIntent.putExtra(
                BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(dicoverableIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

        BluetoothServerSocket bluetoothServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket serverSocketTmp = null;
            try {
                serverSocketTmp = bluetoothAdapter
                        .listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Bluetooth APP",
                                serverUuid);
                bluetoothServerSocket = serverSocketTmp;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    socket = bluetoothServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (socket != null) {
                    // TODO: Managed Connection

                    // TODO: Envoyer Bonjour et Bienvenue

                    try {
                        bluetoothServerSocket.close();
                        break;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            super.run();
        }

        private void cancel() {
            try {
                bluetoothServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

        BluetoothSocket socket;
        BluetoothDevice device;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            this.device = device;

            BluetoothSocket socketTmp = null;
            try {
                socketTmp = device
                        .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(serverUuid);
                socket = socketTmp;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                socket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            // TODO: Manage connection

            super.run();
        }

        private void cancel() {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            bluetoothSocket = socket;

            InputStream inputStreamTmp = null;
            OutputStream outputStreamTmp = null;

            try {
                inputStreamTmp = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
                outputStreamTmp = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            inputStream = inputStreamTmp;
            outputStream = outputStreamTmp;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    // TODO: Envoyer message à l'affichage
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }

            super.run();
        }

        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                outputStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

i get this code from a website, so please how i can us it to send a 'hello world' bettween two smartphone ?

please i need help

thank you

Comment: Try something before posting on SO. We will help you if we see efforts.

Comment: i swear am all testing but i dont know how send a text please help me please

Comment: Have you tried looking after this [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2_r1/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChat.java).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ConnectedThread`:

How to send any data.

```
//Code to send text
String text = "Example";
mConnectedThread.write(text.getBytes());
```

How to receive the sent text (array length is 1024 and 1024 bytes is 1 KB), modify the `run()` method in `ConnectedThread`

```
@Override
public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes;

    while (true) {
        try {
            bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);

            //Received text is here
            String text = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
            Log.d(TAG, text);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }

    super.run();
}
```

After checking your code, it seems the threads haven't been started